# Area preserving maps in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Perhaps this is a naive question (and certainly an idle one):

If $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth diffeomorphism with the property that for any compact surface $\Sigma\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ one has

$$Area(\phi(\Sigma))=Area(\Sigma)$$

is $\phi$ necessarily an isometry? Here we are using the euclidean metric.

If the map is distance preserving then it is an isometry by a theorem of Myers and Steenrod (see [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Myers-Steenrod+theorem) for instance).
If the map is only volume preserving then it could be affine (or worse) so the result couldn't hold.

I had thought perhaps to approximate geodesics by thin tubes but couldn't see how any such argument wouldn't also hold for volume preserving maps.

Comment: This reduces to an infinitesimal problem of characterizing the linear maps $L : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ which preserve cross product lengths, and it's an undergrad linear algebra-level homework problem to show those are isometries.  IMO this is more appropriate for math.stackexchange. 

Comment: Your right I was thinking about things the wrong way.  I just got hung up on the tubes.